# Hypothesis testing: rejection region depends on significance level or vice versa?

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing

Consider the following example. We have 2 coins: Coin 0, which has probability of heads equal to 0.5, and Coin 1, which has probability of heads equal to 0.7. We select one of the 2 coins (without knowing which it is) and flip it 10 times. We have $H_0$: coin 0, and $H_1$: coin 1.

Let $X$ be the number of heads we land on. It seems to reasonable to accept the null hypothesis if $$\frac{P(H_0|x)}{P(H_1|x)}=\frac{P(H_0)}{P(H_1)}\frac{P(x|H_0)}{P(x|H_1)}>1$$ i,e. if the likelihood ratio is $$\frac{P(x|H_0)}{P(x|H_1)} > \frac{1}{P(H_0)/P(H_1)}=:c$$ This is something we can compute using the binomial distribution. So we accept the null hypothesis if $$\frac{(0.5)^{x}(1-0.5)^{10-x}}{(0.7)^{x}(1-0.3)^{10-x}}=\left(\frac{0.5}{0.3}\right)^{10}\left(\frac{0.3}{0.7}\right)^{x} > \frac{1}{0.5/0.7} = 1.4.$$

[image]

Then by considering the above table of values, we see that we are to accept $H_0$ for $X<6$ and reject it in favour of $H_1$ for $X\geq 6.$ And the significance level of the test is given by $\alpha=P(\text{reject }H_0 | H_0)=P(X\geq 6|H_0)=0.38$ using the binomial distribution.

Unless I've done something wrong here, it seems obvious to me that we use the likelihood ratio to see that the rejection region is $X\geq 6$ and from that we compute $\alpha$. Where I'm confused is that my notes (which have omitted these calculations) seem to suggest it should be the other way around.

They say that we fix $\alpha$ before the test, that because the likelihood ratio is $\left(\frac{0.5}{0.3}\right)^{10}\left(\frac{0.3}{0.7}\right)^{x}$, then we reject $H_0$ when the likelihood ratio is small, i.e. if $x$ is large. So we reject $H_0$ if $x>c$, where $c$ is a constant chosen so that $P(X>c |H_0)=\alpha$, the desired significance level of the test.

Firstly I think $c$ is being used to mean different things (1.4, 6 and 7) just in this one example, right? That's pretty confusing notation but putting that aside, doesn't this way of doing it just ignore what the likelihood ratio test is telling us? That we reject the null for $X\geq 6$, which according to the Neyman Pearson is the most optimal way for this simple versus simple case?

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up two different approaches to hypothesis testing when you write   $$\text{It seems to reasonable to accept the null hypothesis if}~~ \frac{P(H_0\mid x)}{P(H_1|\mid x)}=\frac{P(H_0)}{P(H_1)}\frac{P(x\mid H_0)}{P(x\mid H_1)}>1$$ which is what a Bayesian would do, and later talk about Neyman-Pearson optimality.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ah that's very possible actually. Is the first way of doing it where we don't fix $\alpha$ beforehand the Bayesian way and the second way (my lecturer's notes) the Neyman-Pearson stuff?

Comment: The Bayesian approach minimizes the _average probability of error_ $\bar{P}_e=P(H_0)P_{e,0}+P(H_1)P_{e,1}$ where $P_{e_i}$ is the probability of error when Hypothesis $i$ is true, that is, $P_{e,0}$ is the false-alarm probability while $P_{e.1}$ is the missed-detection probability (equals $1-\beta$ where $\beta$ is the power of the test). The Neyman-Pearson test is the one that maximizes $\beta$ over all tests that have false-alarm probability $P_{e,0}$ no larger than a given level $\alpha$. The NP theorem is that the NP test can always be expressed as a threshold test on the likelihood ratio.

Comment: So, in the Bayesian approach, $P_{e,0}$ is whatever the test gives you, and the $P_{e,0}$ might or might not be smaller than the $\alpha$ that you want to set as the largest acceptable value of $P_{e,0}$. The NP test guarantees that $P_{e,0}\leq \alpha$ and gives the smallest $P_{e,1}$ subject to this constraint, but does not necessarily  result in $\bar{P}_e$ being as small as possible. In the NP test, the threshold for the LR is determined by $\alpha$; in the Bayesian test, the threshold is always $\frac{P(H_1)}{P(H_0)}$ (for the LR test the way that _you_ have defined the LR).